# Is it Possible to Integrate Third Party Sellers in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Well the Title says all, I am making a woo-commerce website for selling products as in India it is banned to stock someone else products and sell them on own website, So I want to make it like when a user orders a product an notification to me and the real seller of the product is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your WordPress admin panel > WooCommerce > Settings > Emails > New Order

Make sure "Enable this email notification" is checked.

In Recipient(s), type in the email address that you want to receive order notifications.